# Element offset and client positions in BHO

Tags: c#, html, bho

How to find the position of the `HTMLElement` in BHO(C#)?

I need both offset position of the element in the page and the client position of the element i.e. position of the element from the Left-Top of the client window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem myself.

The getClientRects() and getBoudningClientRect() methods of IHTMLElement2 are very helpful with this regard.

-Datte